# Protractor tests with Muliple browsers got failed at startup

Tags: automation, protractor

I am trying to run e2e tests for chrome and firefox and I am unable to load the chrome browser with following configuration ,any comment is  much appreciated , thanks

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            specs: [ **some spec**
            ],
    multiCapabilities: [{
        "browserName": "firefox"
    },
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
    }
    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 200000,
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'test-result',
            preserveDirectory: false,
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            screenshotsSubfolder: 'images'
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());
    }
};
```

Comment: what error you are getting ? did your node gets registered to hub ?

Comment: @AmitJain thanks for headsup, yes it was configured to pipeline,  how ever  i am trying run in locally , here is the error i got 
`WebDriverError: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process`

Comment: try `directConnect: true` instead of using `seleniumAddress: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`
or make sure your server is running, this is the command for that `webdriver-manager start`

Comment: I would also suggest that **this may be a permission issue** so once you make sure your hub is up and running at url you provided
**try running your config file with admin permissions from cmd**
 
This is the place from where chromedriver is picked to execute your tests
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium

Comment: @AmitJain  thanks a lot !! problem solved with  using direct connect true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `directConnect: true` instead of using `seleniumAddress: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

or make sure your grid server is up and running and also selenium server is up and running

command to start selenium server `webdriver-manager start`